# Algebraic manipulation under modulus of $ t + p \equiv 2t + q\pmod n $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

## Question 1

Can I subtract $t$ from both sides of

$$ t+p \equiv 2t+q\pmod n $$

to get

$$ p \equiv t+q\pmod n$$

## Question 2

Furthermore, can I subtract $q$ from both sides to get

$$ p-q \equiv t\pmod n$$

## Question 3

Are these manipulations still valid if $p$ equals $0$?

## Comments:

I am going off of the following property:

If $ a \equiv b\pmod n$ and $ c \equiv d\pmod n$, then $ a-c \equiv b-d\pmod n$.

My thought for the first question is let $a := t+p$, $b := 2t+q$, $c := t$, $d := t$, then apply the property.

Question 2 can be handled the same way but with different assignments for $a,b,c,d$.

I don't have much intuition for algebraic manipulations involving modulus equivalences, so I want to be extra sure by asking there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1 You can do that operation.

Q2 You can do that operation.

Q3 operations are valid also when $p=0$.

$ a \equiv b\pmod n$ and $ c \equiv d\pmod n$ implies $n \mid a-b$ and $n \mid c-d$. Thus $n \mid (a-b)-(c-d) = (a-c)-(b-d) \implies  a-c \equiv b-d\pmod n$.